# Could a steamship be built somewhere during the 14th-17th century?

Tags: technology, alternate-history

Could an earlier and simple variation of the steamship be built around the 14th-17th century? If not, are there alternatives to having a ship not powered by sails?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can my ancient Roman civilization develop effective steam power for use in ships?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/98073/how-can-my-ancient-roman-civilization-develop-effective-steam-power-for-use-in-s) .

Comment: You'll probably be interested in the *Ring of Fire* series by Eric Flint et al., where an American town time-travels to 1632 Thuringia and starts a technological revolution. Among other things, simple steam designs are discussed at length (both in *RoF* and in the *Grantville Gazette* that accompanies the series).

Comment: A somewhat one-sided discussion of "earliest time X can be invented" questions is occurring [here, on Meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7203/40609).  It will give you insight into how to better ask this question and keep it from being closed as [primarily opinion-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436#6437).

Comment: @LSerni a whole town!  That's a great series to point people to.  I can believe a whole town with all its infrastructure, skills, and trained people.  Great comment!

Comment: Another series on the topic, specifically targeting steamships (but earlier in time) is *The Emperor's Men*. German seamen find themselves in the late Roman Empire and must teach weapons and steam if they want to survive.